# What does "broke from formation" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

> One plane ***broke from formation*** and headed to the sky.

I don't understand what that means.- to break from formation

Does that mean that the plane was out of line?

Comment: Search for "break formation". It means the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

> One plane **broke from** formation and headed to the sky.

This is a

> formation

[image]

This is

> **breaking** from formation

[image]